# Which of the following two methods do you use to convert untyped values to typed values at the boundaries?

Tags: typescript, architecture

In languages like python and typescript where there is an `any` type, database query() functions return `object`s/`dict`s with `any` type.

When your column names/field names are same in both the database, would you do:

```js
type Foo {
  foo: string,
  bar: string
}

// Method 1.
function foo1(): Foo {
    let row = queryDB() // row: any
    return row
}
```

or

```js
// Method 2.
function foo2(): Foo {
    row = queryDB() // row: any
    let ret: Foo = {
       foo: row['foo'],
       bar: row['bar']
    }
    return ret;
}
```

I have seen codebases doing both of these but I am not sure of the maintainability, correctness or performance implications of these.

For example, it can be imagined that you renamed the column `bar` to `baz` in the database, and forgot to update the code.

In the case of `foo1`, the error will be raised in some remote part of the code which tried to access `bar` and you have no idea why `bar` is undefined. Whereas in the case of `foo2` the error will be raised in line 4 of `foo2`.

On the other hand, `foo2` is wasting cycles shallow cloning the row.

And if you add a column to Foo table, there are now three places to update in the case of `foo2`: DB schema, `type Foo` and `Foo = {..}` in `foo2`.
Whereas there are only two places to update in `foo1`.

What would an experienced developer do in cases like this? and why?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you think about maintainability, you should avoid `let` and other mutations.
Once you received something from database - can't be mutated. It can be updated, converted, formated - but not mutated.

COnsider this code:

```js
type Foo = {
    foo: string,
    bar: string
}

const queryDB = (): Promise<any> =>
    Promise.resolve({
        foo: 'foo',
        bar: 'bar'
    })

// Method 1.
async function foo1() {
    const row = await queryDB() // any
    return row
}
```

Unfortunatelly, TS on his own can't help you much if you are retreiving something from the server. It should be validated in runtime.

If you want to make sure that `queryDB` returns `Foo` data type, you need to do runtime validation.

```js
import * as t from 'io-ts'
import { PathReporter } from 'io-ts/lib/PathReporter'

const Foo = t.type({
    foo: t.string,
    bar: t.string
})

type Foo = t.TypeOf<typeof Foo>


const queryDB = (): Promise<any> =>
    Promise.resolve({
        foo: 'foo',
        bar: 'bar'
    })

// Method 1.
async function foo1() {
    const row = await queryDB() // any

    const result = Foo.decode(row)

    console.log(PathReporter.report(result)) // error should be reported
}
```

If you are interested in functional programming, [io-ts](https://gcanti.github.io/io-ts/docs/modules) can help you to make such kind of validation.

Please be aware that there are a lot of runtime validators. I have shown you only the one of them.

Comment: I use Zod which is inspired by io-ts for validation JSON sent by clients. But I was wondering if its worth it in the case of DB, because I control the DB schema, and the DB schema and type are supposed to be the same. If they are different, it's a bug. Is it appropriate to do runtime validation in this case?

Comment: @Farseen if you have a small object with several keys - it worth it. If you have a big object with nested properties - don't do it. I have worked on several projects in last 3 years and I have never seen runtype validation. I think if you have full control over the backend - you can skip runtime validation. But this is only my opinion. It is better to discuss with your teammates